# Remove similar elements in array of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, unique

I have an array of numbers, like: `[1, 4, 7, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]`.

I would like to remove duplicate elements and sort the result, i.e. the required result is:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 7]`.

Is there any built in Javascript/jQuery functions to do this, or I must write my own ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there's nothing built-in. Also, you need to be aware that the default sort is lexical, so `[9, 1, 10].sort()` will return `[1, 10, 9]`.

The following will sort and remove duplicates from an array of numbers in place:

```
function sortAndRemoveDuplicates(arr) {
    arr.sort( function(a, b) { return a - b; } );
    var copy = arr.slice(0);
    arr.length = 0;

    for (var i = 0, len = copy.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if (i == 0 || copy[i] != copy[i - 1]) {
            arr.push(copy[i]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

var arr = [1, 4, 7, 1, 2, 1, 3, 10, 1, 4, 10];
sortAndRemoveDuplicates(arr);
console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10]
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Underscore library](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) is great for all those kinds of tricks; I love it and wouldn't be able to live without it!!

Once you declare it, you call its functions by using the underscore, like this:

```
_.uniq([1, 4, 7, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]);
=> [1, 4, 7, 2, 3]
```

If you want it sorted:

```
_.uniq([1, 4, 7, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]).sort();
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
```

From the page linked above:

*"Underscore provides 60-odd functions that support both the usual functional suspects: map, select, invoke — as well as more specialized helpers: function binding, javascript templating, deep equality testing, and so on."*

Comment: +1 for Underscore -- but if the OP is asking for a javascript function that does what `uniq` does, why not pull it out to solve his problem, and then point out that all this and more can be found in the library?  :-)

Comment: Well... _.uniq uses _.reduce which uses _.each... That would not be very explicit...

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.prototype.unique = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        if( this.indexOf(this[i], i+1) != -1 ){
            this.splice(i,1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return this.sort();
}

var x = [1,'x', 4, 7, 1, 2, 1,'x', 3, 1, 4];
x.unique() // [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, "x"]
```

Answer (score 1):

As of JavaScript 1.6, **array.filter()** can be used to remove duplicate values:

```
[1, 4, 7, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]
    .filter(function (value, index, self) {
        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
});
```

returns

```
[1, 4, 7, 2, 3]
```

What's nice about filter is it works on all value types in the array:

```
[1, "d", 4, "e", 7, "e", 1, "a", 2, "d", 1, "b", 3, "c", 1, "e", 4]
    .filter(function (value, index, self) {
        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    });
```

returns

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```